# Updating one column on table with value from another table on matching index using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

Table #1 is a file geodatabase feature class with geometries and some limited metadata.

Table #2 is a file geodatabase table with business records.

What tool can I use to find matching records on the two tables, and then update table #1 (the file geodatabase feature class) with columns copied across from table #2?

```
TABLE #1
Field Name  Alias   Data Type   Allow Null  Domain  Default Value   Length
TaskID  TaskID  Long    True            
OBJECTID    OBJECTID    Object ID   False           
SHAPE   SHAPE   Geometry    True            
ProjectName ProjectName Text    True            50

TABLE #2    
Field Name  Alias   Data Type   Allow Null  Domain  Default Value   Length
TaskID  TaskID  Long    True            
SourceReferenceID   SourceReferenceID   Text    True            200
NameOfWorks NameOfWorks Text    True            2000
```

I want to find a match where Table#1 ProjectName = Table#2 NameOfWorks and then take the Table#2.TaskID and update Table#1.TaskID

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, create the new field(s) on Table #1 (if not already done).

Secondly, join the two tables based on your key fields (ProjectName and NameOfWorks) using the 'Add Join' tool (right click on Table #1 in the table of Contents -> Joins and Relates -> Add Join).  See:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-join.htm

If you then look at the Attributes table for Table #1, you'll see the data from Table #2 in extra columns in the same table as Table #1.  Note that this is not a permanent change to the table, it is just a temporary database view.

Thirdly, use the 'Calculate Field' tool (right click Table #1 column header in the Attribute Table -> Calculate Field) to copy the values from the Table #2 version of the column to the Table #1 version of the column.  See:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm .  For the 'Expression' in Calculate Field tool, just double-click on the equivaluent Table #2 field in the 'Fields' list in the tool and it will add it to the expression.  Be careful not to double-click on the Table #1 version of the field instead (they'll probably have similar/same names) as that would result in nothing changing at all.

Repeat that last step for each field that you want to copy from Table #2 to Table #1.

Lastly, remove the Join from the Table #1 (right click it in table of Contents -> Joins and Relates -> Remove All Joins).  The Table #2 columns will disappear from the attributes table, but the calculated values in the new Table #1 columns will remain.